# Configure c++ debugger in VSCode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I recently moved to VSCode and im a little be lost.

If i compile my program with this console command

```
g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp src/*.cpp -I included
```

It compiles and generates the .exe file correctly.

But i  have a bug in it, so i want to use the debugger to know what is happening.
When i hit run -> star debuggin in VSCode i get a console message of "not such file or directory" for one of my included files. So, i think i have some wrong configuration in my launch.json

launch.json

```json
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:\\Users\\Don\\Desktop\\IColections\\main.exe",
            "args": ["-I[included/*/*.h]"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\Users\\Don\\Desktop\\IColections",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo"
        }
    ]
}
```

i do not relly underestand what should i put in args or environment

EDIT:

this is the error message

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g *.cpp -o C:\Users\Don\Desktop\IColections\main.exe
main.cpp:2:31: fatal error: ../included/Fruta.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../included/Fruta.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
```

and this is main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "../included/Fruta.h"
#include "../included/Uva.h"
#include "../included/Naranja.h"
#include "../included/List.h"
#include "../included/List_Iterator.h"

int main(){
    
    ICollection* fruta = new List;
    
    Uva* misUvas = new Uva;
    misUvas->setKg(80.5);
    misUvas->setRacimos(15000);

    Naranja* misNaranjas = new Naranja;
    misNaranjas->setKg(200);
    misNaranjas->setNaranjas(1000);

    fruta->agregar(misNaranjas);
    fruta->agregar(misUvas);

    IIterator* it = dynamic_cast<List*> (fruta)->getIterator();    

    ICollectible* elem;
    Fruta* frut;

    if(!it->hasCurrent()){
    }

    while(it->hasCurrent()){ 
        elem = it->getCurrent();
        frut = dynamic_cast <Fruta*> (elem); 
        frut->printFruta();
        it->next();
    }

    system("pause");
    



    return 0;
}
```

tasks.json

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Tarea generada por el depurador."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error? `"args": ["-I[included/*/*.h]"],` already looks wrong, I'm not sure what's it for.

Comment: The vscode documentation has nothing in args: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp)

Comment: First thing first, add `-g` to the compilation command.

Comment: ***i do not relly underestand what should i put in args or environment*** Does your program use the command line arguments or environment?

Comment: i Edited the post, added the exact error message and the code of main.cpp (the one that gives error)
I think my program dont use them @drescherjm but i dont know what arguments or enviroment are for VSCode

Comment: Your main does not take any arguments. `int main(){` it does not use any environment variables either.

Comment: If you already have a compiled version with debug information (-g) then you do not need to include the header files again.

Comment: `"args": ["-I[included/*/*.h]"],` should be `"args": [],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a compiled version with debug information (-g) then you do not need to include the header files again.

Just remove the line "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo" from the configuration since your program is already compiled.